# if access is not installed will my program still operate

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access

I am developing a program that retrieves information from Excel files and converts that information to store it in an Access Database and use it later. 
The computer that the program will operate on does have Excel installed, but i am not sure whether it has Access. 
I was just wondering will my program work in this case or Access should definitely be installed on the other computer?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is : it depends.

- If you are targeting `mdb` Access files, the [Jet database engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) comes pre-installed with Windows, so you do not need to install anything (make sure it's compiled for `x86` though, not `AnyCPU` or it may not work on 64bit systems).
- If you are using the Access 2007/2010/2013 newer `accdb` format, the target machine must have the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) installed (as [KekySemau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13111352/3811) answered).
  Be careful though: you can only install either the 32bit *or* 64bit version, and your own program bitness must match that of the driver.
  Also, if the user has another version of MS Office installed (32bit or 64bit), you won't be able to install the engine (although it should already be installed if they have Office 2007 or a later version).

Short answer: if you stick with `mdb`, you don't need to install anything additional.
In any case, make sure you compile your C# app for the `x86` architecture explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The user may need to install the Access DataBase Engine (free download):
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

> ODBC and OLEDB drivers are installed for application developers to use in developing their applications with connectivity to Office file formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft OleDbConnection you need to install the [Access Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4438) on the client PC.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this is not true. While installing the Runtime will provide the necessary drivers, it's not required as all you need is the Access Database Engine if you want to use the newer `` `.accdb` database. For MDB files, you don't need anything, windows comes with pre-installed drivers.