# access 2010 runtime installation on other machines

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've created an access 2010 application with forms, linked tables, and vba code. Some users don't have access on their PCs and also do not have installation rights to install applications on their PCs as well. If I package a access 2010 application, do they need to install anything when they run it, or does it just run as a stand alone app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users will need FULL installing rights. Remember, the Access runtime is the SAME as the full edition. That is a 175+ meg  install, often requires a re-boot, and also requires you to install service packs. Make no mistake here, installing the Access runtime must install VBA, the ribbon system, and MANY other parts that are SHARED by the office system. This is really the same as a FULL BLOWN office install. Any kind of thinking that the Access running is ANY DIFFERENT then the full edition of installing office needs to be squashed on your part.

Once the above huge office install of the Access runtime has occurred then you can simply copy any mde, acdDE and including your application to that target computer. Uses then can double click on those Access applications to launch Access (full or runtime).

So there is no special “association” between the application you create and build in Access and the Access runtime. They are separate installs and your application does not need to be installed, but simply copied to the target computer.

If the target computer has full edition of office/Access or the above access runtime installed, then your application can run.

However, users need the SAME rights for installing full editions of office or the huge Access runtime which is in effect an “office” install. The user permissions and requirements for installing the FULL edition Office, Access, or installing the Access runtime are the SAME.

So users need full installing rights, and they require the SAME rights to install full edition of office or the office edition + Access runtime. (they are the same).

Answer (score 0):

They should be able to run it as a standalone app Access Pro isn't required. In my environment I simply publish an ACCDE file and provide that to the users.  Just make sure they have access to the location where your backend file is stored and that it is the same path.

Comment: do they need access runtime installed?

Comment: With anything pre-2007 doesn't require anything at all.  Though anything 2007 and after require at least the Access Database Engine installed, free from MS.   You can review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109594/if-access-is-not-installed-will-my-program-still-operate/13111352#13111352 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just need the Access Runtime. If you are having problems on computers that don't have Access installed just use this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910

You have 32bits and 64bits version.